# Can I have two parallel receive task in Camunda?

Tags: java, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda, camunda-modeler

Is it possible? Or Camunda doesn't allow parallel receive task? 
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/bpmn20/tasks/receive-task/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what message you are waiting for.
If you wait in each task for a different message there should be no problem and you can model several receive tasks behind a parallel gateway.
But if all the tasks are waiting for the same message I would suggest a different modelling -stategy. Just wait for the message with a single receive message task (or event) and after the message is received you can split the flow with a parallel gateway.

I hope that answers your question

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the solution suggested my @MuffinMICHI , the first approach can be acomplished as follows : Here I have list of directories:
[image]